# Pushing off another object — why does the other object do work on you without expending any energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, free-body-diagram

Suppose you are in space (or on a frictionless surface) next to another object of the same mass $m$ as you. Take the reference frame of the center of mass of you and the object (so there is zero velocity initially). Now suppose you push on the object with a constant force $F$ for some time $\Delta t$ to "jump off" the object.

During the time $\Delta t$, there is an acceleration $a = F/m$ for both you and the object in opposite directions. The final velocities of you and the object are $v = a\Delta t$.

The object has final kinetic energy $KE = \frac{1}{2}ma^{2}\Delta t^{2}$ and you have final kinetic energy $KE = \frac{1}{2}ma^{2}\Delta t^{2}$. Together, there is total kinetic energy
$$ KE = ma^{2}\Delta t^{2}. $$

The work done by you on the object is $W = F\cdot \frac{1}{2}a\Delta t^{2} = \frac{1}{2}ma^{2}\Delta t^{2}$, so this is how much potential/chemical energy you've transferred from yourself to the other object in the form of kinetic energy.

Now the issue is, this only accounts for half of the total kinetic energy. There is also work done by the object on you, but the issue is, that other object didn't have any potential energy. So how can the other object do work on you, without transferring any energy to you? What is the right way to think about this situation?

Comment: I feel like it's even worse than you think. The object is doing *negative* work on you, because the point of contact (your feet on the rock) is actually going to move *backwards* (i.e., in the opposite direction of your eventual motion) during the jump!  The thing is, the kinetic energy of your body doesn't come from the rock doing work on you, it comes from stored chemical energy in *your body*.

Comment: Suppose you glued your hand to the rock, and just before your arm finished straightening out, a space ninja jumped out and chopped your arm off. Then your arm (with its decreased chemical potential energy) would be attached to the rock's center of mass, not your center of mass, but you'd still both be moving away from the ninja at $v$. This illustrates how kinetic energy and potential energy are system properties, not object properties; how the boundaries of parts of a system are arbitrary; and how you should always be on your guard for ninjas, even in space.

Comment: This post (addressing the more general question on the work-energy theorem in the context of extended bodies) is very helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/628906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is also work done by the object on you, but the issue is, that other object didn't have any potential energy. So how can the other object do work on you, without transferring any energy to you?

In this problem energy transfers only from you to the object.

Consider, as a model, that the object is a rigid block and you are a block attached to a compressed spring. Now, as you are pushing the object to the right, the point of contact moves to the right. So the force on the object has a positive power $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$, while the force acting on you has a negative power $-P=-\vec F \cdot \vec v$. So power goes into the block and power goes out of you.

Now, in the process of pushing the spring is extending twice as fast as the block is moving. So you are losing elastic energy twice as fast as you are transferring mechanical energy, so half of the elastic energy you lose stays with you and does not go out. But this energy is no longer elastic, it is now kinetic energy.

So the blocks increased KE is due to you doing work on it. Your increased KE is not due to any work (which is a transfer of energy). Instead it is an internal change of energy from elastic to kinetic.

The force from the block on you increases your momentum, but does not increase your energy.

Comment: I would argue that in the OP's case, the object *is* doing work on the body, but it is in fact *negative* work: the point of contact (the person's feet with the object), is in fact going to be moving *backward* during the jump, so the force exerted by the object on the feet is in the direction *opposite* to the motion of the feet: negative work.  On another note: I agree that the energy of motion of the person comes from inside the personL you've modeled it as a "spring", but really it comes from stored *chemical* energy in the body.  The body is not spring-like.

Comment: I think I didn't read your second paragraph well enough: you've put things in terms of power transfer rather than work (as I said above in the comment), so nevermind.

Comment: If the spring is doing positive work on the object, and as this is happening the object is applying the opposite force on the spring (which is part of you, the block + spring system), how is the object not doing (negative) work on you? Suppose at the end you and the object both have a kinetic energy of $W$ each. Initially you only have $2W$ of elastic energy, and in the final state you only have $W$ of kinetic energy, so the object must have done a work of $-W$ on you.

Comment: @Puk “how is the object not doing (negative) work on you?” I explicitly stated that already, please read the 2nd paragraph more carefully. “Initially you only have 2W of elastic energy, and in the final state you only have W of kinetic energy, so the object must have done a work of −W on you”. Please read the 3rd paragraph more carefully.

Comment: I did read carefully and I have no problem with anything you say in paragraphs 2 and 3. My comment is on your very first sentence: "There is no work done by the object on you." How is this consistent with the object doing negative work on you?

Comment: @Puk it is a matter of the translation from math to English. If there is a force from system A acting on B and the associated power is negative, then that is best stated in English as B doing work on A, not as A doing negative work on B. The OP is clearly using this usage, so to use it otherwise would be confusing. If the sign of the power is unknown then you should not state it as either work by A on B or by B on A but simply a signed power.

Comment: @Dale The reason I thought there ought to be positive work (or power) by the force acting on you is that I was thinking about the center of masses of the objects, not the point of contact. The point of contact is moving to the right, but the CoM of the left object ("you") is moving to the left. My question is, why are we looking at the point of contact as opposed to the center of mass of the left object? How _do_ you define power?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal that is the big mistake encouraged by the usual presentations of the work energy theorem. The actual mechanical power is given by $P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of the force $\vec F$. The center of mass is not relevant for mechanical power

Comment: @Dale why are you saying the object doesn’t do work on the person? Doesn’t negative work qualify as work?

Comment: @BobD saying that the object does negative work on the person is confusing. It also is not the way that the OP intended. The OP thought that the object did work on the person meaning positive work.

Comment: @Dale is it any more confusing than saying gravity does negative work on an object being lifted, which we frequently refer to? All we are saying is the direction of the force acting on an object is opposite to its displacement so that it takes energy away from the object

Comment: @BobD the way we teach these concepts, IMO, is almost designed to produce confusion. I have noticed the confusion in many new students, but also in very proficient people like yourself. If I had my way we wouldn’t even speak of A doing work on B. We would simply calculate mechanical power and if it is negative say mechanical power is leaving the system and if it is positive say mechanical power is entering the system. No “on” or “by” and very little “work”. Think of the relative emphasis on force vs impulse. That should be the relative emphasis of power vs work, IMO

Comment: @Dale I greatly respect your opinion, but without acknowledging that work can be positive or negative it seems to me the term “net work” becomes meaningless and with it things like the work energy theorem. No need to respond further, just expressing my concern.

Comment: @BobD I specifically object to the presentation of the work energy theorem and the term “net work” as used there. The way it is presented is the key reason for most of the confusion on this topic, with the term “net work” causing the bulk of the confusion. You can see that the work energy theorem is the root of the problem here where the OP focused on the motion of the center of mass. That led him to believe that the object was doing (positive) work on the person.

Comment: What can I say. The work energy theorem is pretty mainstream in physics. I’ve found it useful and would hesitate to abandon it. Anyway, thanks for responding

Comment: @BobD I am not saying to abandon it. I am saying that the way it is taught breeds confusion. This question is an example.

Comment: @Dale Ehh I actually did find the opening sentence confusing. I think you should instead say, _"There is no [positive] work done by the object on you [(although there is negative work)]."_

Comment: @MaximalIdeal I have deleted that sentence, but I will not say it that way as I think it causes more confusion than it resolves to say it that way

Comment: @Puk et al: it may be helpful to assign a mathematical object to every mode that the system has for holding energy. Then the mathematical object that holds spring potential energy does $W$ on the object that holds the astronaut's kinetic energy and $W$ on the object that holds the rock's kinetic energy. "A does $W$ on both B and C" and "B and C both do $-W$ on A" are identical statements. "C does $-W$ on B" is not identical and does not follow, even if the real life antecedent of B is glued to the real life antecedent of A.

Comment: @Dale Do you know of any reference (book/paper/lecture/etc.) that discusses this nuance? If not, is there anything you think states the WE theorem (or power theorem?) correctly and carefully?

Comment: @Dale With all respect, but I see your explanation confusing, because a) you just shift sign problem from work to power and b) you can only have negative power if you let a system perform a negative elementary work, since by definition power is $P=\frac {dW}{dt}$, so, $-P=\frac {-dW}{dt}$. Hence, if you ignore negative work concept, but accept negative power concept,- your understanding is vague with "double standards".

Answer (score 4):

Often one has to be careful including the forces applied, work done by etc, by the human body so I will first include you as an inanimate object.

System - you, object and a device which I will elaborate on later.
The device exerts a constant magnitude force on you and the object but in opposite directions.

The free body diagrams are shown below with the magnitudes of all the forces being the same, $F$.

[image]

Suppose the separation between you and the object increase by $d$, ie you move $d/2$ and the object moves $d/2$ to the right with the device not moving at all.

The device does work $F_{\rm yd}\cdot d/2$ on you and the device does work $F_{\rm od}\cdot d/2$ and no work is done on the device because it does not move.

Doing the sums it can be shown that the total work done by the device, $Fd/2+Fd/2=Fd$ is equal to the kinetic energy gained by you and the object $2\times \frac 12 m v_{\rm final}$ where $v_{\rm final}$ is the final speed of both you and the object after separation with energy being conserved.

Now what is this device?
It could be some sort of spring arrangement with stored elastic potential energy or it could be a cylinder which has massless and frictionless pistons at each end with a chemical reaction (explosion) going on inside the cylinder.

However in this case it the parts of you body, the muscles, which allow you to move using up chemical energy.
The process of what actually happens is very complex as your body can no longer be assumed to be rigid and the forces are being generated by the **contraction** of your muscles.
Note that if it is your hand that does the pushing, the hand in contact with the object will have to be moving at the same velocity as the object.

Although what happens between the initial and final state is so complex that I have not attempted to describe it in any detail, I hope that I have shown you that it is you who has to do all of the work.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worthwhile here to first make sure that  assigning the qualifications 'positive work' and 'negative work' is done in a guaranteed consistent way.

Simplest instance: in celestial mechanics: a small object orbiting a far heavier primary. I will refer to the two objects as 'primary' and 'secondary'.

Let the secondary be in an eccentric orbit. Example: the orbit of Halley's comet. When Halley's comet is on its way to its point of closest approach (to the Sun) the Sun's gravity is doing positive work, increasing the velocity of Halley's comet. The comet goes along its point of closest approach, and from there starts climbing again. During the climbing phase the Sun's gravity is doing negative work on Halley's comet.

There are two aspects to get right.
There is the *sign* of some particular work done, and there is the issue of attribution: which object is doing that work.

Next we move to a case that is one degree less simple:

Let there be two celestial bodies, of equal mass, orbiting each other, in eccentric orbit.

The two celestial bodies are continuously doing work upon each other. During the contracting phase of the orbit each is doing positive work upon the *other* celestial body, increasing the velocity of the other celestial body. Conversely, when the two celestial bodies are swinging away from each other again both are doing negative work upon the *other* celestial body.

Next example: the case described in the answer by Farcher: two objects of equal mass, and a device that that acts like a gas spring. When the piston of the gas spring is pushed into the cilinder the gas spring converts the work done to potential energy.

During compression of the gas spring: the work done *by the gas pressure* is negative work. When the gas spring expands again the gas pressure is doing positive work.

We set up a collision of the two objects, in such a way that the kinetic energy of the objects converts to potential energy stored in the gas spring, and then the gas spring pushes the two objects apart again.

Now, returning to the case of gravitational interaction for a moment: we could choose to describe that interaction in terms of storing gravitational potential energy, but that is unpractical. The practical choice is to treat the case as a direct object-to-object force. Do that consistently, and no self-contradiction will arise.

Now the case where the gas spring is acting as a repulsive force between the two objects.

We have the option of treating that repulsion as a generic repulsion, and think of the case as two objects, exerting a repulsive force directly upon each other. As long as we *consistently* treat the case in terms of exerting a force directly upon each other no self-contradiction will arise.

The other option is to treat the gas spring explicitly as a participating factor. Then there is no longer such a thing as object A doing work upon object B. All tracking of force and doing work must be expressed in terms of a *pair* of participating factors. When you treat the gas spring explicitly as a participating factor then you have two pairs: object A and the gas spring, and object B and the gas spring.

Let two objects be initially adjacent. You have a gas spring that can be locked in compressed state, ready to be released with a trigger

You compress the gas spring, and you position the gas spring in between the two objects. Upon releasing the gas spring: the gas spring is doing work on both of the objects, accelerating them away from each other.

Summerizing:
Treated as two objects exerting a repulsive force directly upon each other: as the objects accelerate away from each other each object is doing positive work upon the other object.

Treated with *explicit* participation of the entity that interconverts kinetic and potential energy: work done by the objects is work done upon that energy interconverting entity. Work done by the energy interconverting entity is done upon the objects.

Comment: Thank you for the lucid analysis. I gather there are _three_ ways to analyze the situation: (1) two objects exerting a repulsive force upon each other with distances/velocities as tracked by the _center of masses_, (2) three entities where one is an intermediate entity interconverting KE and PE, and (3) two objects exerting a force upon each other with distances/velocities as tracked by the _point of contact_. (1) and (2) are described by your post, and (3) is given by @Dale's post. That much I understand so far.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal I'm not sure how to understand that notion of 'tracking by point of contact'. The motion must be tracked relative to an inertial coordinate system. A natural candidate for that is the one you used in your question: the coordinate system that is co-moving with the common center of mass of the objects that are involved. Per the principle of relativity of inertial motion: you can use any member of the equivalence class of inertial coordinate systems; the requirement is to be consistent: keep using the same inertial coordinate system throughout.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal About self-consistency. I prefer to think of 'work done' as a process of energy *conversion*, not as 'transfer of energy'. To show the difference: I have had someone adamantly insist to me the following: when you have a vehicle that carries its own energy supply (example: electric car) then when that car is accelerating no work is done, because there is no *transfer* of energy. You get the picture: insisting to define 'work done' as 'transfer of energy' is doomed to fail. By contrast: defining 'work done' as *conversion* of energy assures self-consistent representation.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understand how to think about my question in a way that I can put into my own words. I will address the last part of my OP, which said,

> There is also work done by the object on you, but the issue is, that other object didn't have any potential energy. So how can the other object do work on you, without transferring any energy to you? What is the right way to think about this situation?

The issue stemmed from confusing *how work is treated in an intro mechanics course* vs *how work is treated in a thermodynamics course*. See the linked posts at the end of this post. Also, we should point out that for extended bodies there is a difference between body forces and contact forces. I will focus only on contact forces in this discussion (so no gravity or electromagnetism).

---

### Work

As pointed out in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/628906) and [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/750141), there is a difference between "work due to a particular force" and the "center of mass work"/"net work"/"pseudowork."

When you are dealing with work due to a particular contact force $F$ on a body/system, you must always track the position at which the force is applied when calculating $dW_{F} = F\, dx$. This is how work is calculated in thermodynamics, and if $F$ is the force done *by* an outside system or environment *on* the system you are interested in, then $W_{F}$ is the energy transfer into the system due to the force $F$.

Summing all such work gives you the energy transfer into the system due to all the contact forces acting on the system. When we add energy transfer due to heat, if any exists, we obtain the equation for the first law of thermodynamics.

Now there is another form of work, commonly called net work, which is invoked in the study of Newtonian mechanics. It is known that when you sum all forces $F_{i}$ acting on a body/system, the center of mass obeys $\sum_{i} F_{i} = MA$ ($M$ being total mass and $A$ being the acceleration of the center of mass) even if the forces are not applied at the center of mass. Now the work-energy theorem then states that if we define $dW_{\text{net}} = F_{\text{net}}\, dX$ (where $F_{\text{net}} = \sum_{i} F_{i}$ and $X$ is the center of mass position), then the change in the translational kinetic energy *associated with the motion of the center of mass* is $\Delta KE = W_{\text{net}}$. Note this theorem, as I stated it, discounts kinetic energy associated with internal motion and it discounts any mention of potential energy.

Remarkably, the two forms of work I pointed out are different, and you don't run into any contradiction if you track all forces carefully enough.

---

### Original Scenario

Now how does all this apply to the original question? Going back to the original scenario, let us take system $1$ ($S_{1}$ for short) to be the person jumping off and let us take system $2$ ($S_{2}$ for short) to be the other object.

Alternatively, we can imagine that we have two blocks with a spring in the middle (the specifics of what mechanism is used to push objects apart or the force law is not important), and we can take $S_{1}$ to be the system consisting of one block plus the spring attached to it and $S_{2}$ to be the system consisting of the other block. Note that in the analysis, we will not need to consider the spring as its own system! Other posts that say the spring or whatever pushes things apart has to be its own system are misleading!

Choose a coordinate system so that (the center of mass of) $S_{1}$ moves in the $+$ direction along some axis and (the center of mass of) $S_{2}$ moves in the $-$ direction along the same axis when the two are pushed apart.

Assume $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are pushed apart and end up with final velocities $v_{f}$ and $-v_{f}$ along some axis. When $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are pushed apart, the potential/chemical energy of $S_{1}$ is converted to the kinetic energies of $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$.

When the two systems are being pushed apart, the following two things are true:

1. Since $S_{1}$ is expanding (either because the person is jumping off in one scenario or the spring is expanding in the other scenario), the contact point is moving in the direction of $S_{2}$ with overall velocity.
2. The center of mass of $S_{1}$ is moving away from $S_{2}$.

Statement (1) concerns the point at which the forces act, so thermodynamic work is relevant. Statement (2) concerns the center of mass, so the center of mass work is relevant.

We have $F_{\text{by 1 on 2}} = -F$ and $F_{\text{by 2 on 1}} = +F$. When considering thermodynamic work, we look at the contact point, whose displacement is $-\Delta x < 0$, and find the following:

- $W_{F_{\text{by 1 on 2}}} = -F\cdot -\Delta x > 0$, and
- $W_{F_{\text{by 2 on 1}}} = +F\cdot -\Delta x < 0$.

The fact that $W_{F_{\text{by 1 on 2}}}$ is positive means that $S_{2}$ is gaining overall energy, and the fact that $W_{F_{\text{by 2 on 1}}}$ is negative means that $S_{1}$ is losing overall energy. This makes perfect sense, because $S_{1}$ is losing potential energy to $S_{2}$ (and the remaining energy that stays with $S_{1}$ is converted to kinetic energy).

When considering the center of mass work, we look at the center of masses. The CoM of $S_{1}$ is displaced by $+\Delta x > 0$ and the CoM of $S_{2}$ is displaced by $-\Delta x < 0$. We find the following:

- $W_{F_{\text{net on 1}}} = +F\cdot +\Delta x > 0$, and
- $W_{F_{\text{net on 2}}} = -F\cdot -\Delta x > 0$.

The net work for each system is positive. This is exactly what is expected by the work-energy theorem: both objects gain kinetic energy and accordingly the center of mass work for both is positive.

---

### Summary

Returning back to

> There is also work done by the object on you, but the issue is, that other object didn't have any potential energy. So how can the other object do work on you, without transferring any energy to you? What is the right way to think about this situation?

We have to clarify what we mean by work.

If by "work" we mean "work due to a contact force," then in the OP scenario, the person jumping off is doing positive work on the other object, and the object is doing negative work on the person, because you must track the point at which the force is applied. Accordingly, the person's total energy decreases and the total energy of the object increases.

If by "work" we mean "net work"/"center of mass work"/"pseudowork", then in the OP scenario there is positive work done on both the person and the object. Accordingly both have an increase in kinetic energy. This of course says nothing about how the total energy is transferred, because the work-energy theorem only deals with changes in kinetic energy only. Thus, there is no issue or contradiction.

**Related:**

- [Does work-energy theorem account for thermal energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/749958/does-work-energy-theorem-account-for-thermal-energy)
- [How is work-energy theorem explained for rigid bodies?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628894/how-is-work-energy-theorem-explained-for-rigid-bodies)
- [A force is exerted on a body, kinetic energy increases but no work is done by the force. Why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/141760/a-force-is-exerted-on-a-body-kinetic-energy-increases-but-no-work-is-done-by-th?rq=1)